# If $A\in M_{5,4}$, $\operatorname{rank}A=3$ and $B\in M_{4,3}$, $\operatorname{rank}B=2$ then $AB$ must be a non-zero matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Answer with TRUE or FALSE and give a proper explanation.

If $A\in M_{5,4}$, $\operatorname{rank}A=3$ and $B\in M_{4,3}$, $\operatorname{rank}B=2$ then $AB$ must be a non-zero matrix.

My approach:

From the information given above we can describe $A$,$B$ and $AB$ like this:

$A:\mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^5$

$B:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$

$AB:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^5$

We know that $\operatorname{rank}A + \dim N(A)=\dim\mathbb{R}^4 \Rightarrow \dim N(A)=1$

$R(B)$,$N(A) \in \mathbb{R^4}$.

Since $\operatorname{rank}B \gt \dim N(A)$ there exists an vector $y$ such that $y\in R(B),y\notin N(A)$. So $y=Bx$ and $Ay\neq0 \Rightarrow ABx\neq 0$.

Now I don't know if the statement is TRUE or FALSE because I've found an vector such that $AB\neq0$ but what if there exists an vector that is both in $R(B)$ and in $N(A)$? That would mean that $AB=0$ and so the answer would be FALSE, but I'm not sure does such an vector exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $R(B)$ has dimension $2$ and $N(A)$ has dimension $1$ (by the Rank-Nullity Theorem), it must be that $R(B)\nsubseteq N(A)$ and thus $AB\neq 0$.

Comment: I'm aware of that,but is it possible that $N(A) \subset R(B)$ ?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is. $AB = 0$ is equivalent to $R(B)\subseteq N(A)$.

Comment: @DraganZrilić As a concrete example, consider the following. Let $\{v_1, \dots, v_4\},  \{u_1,\dots, u_5\}$ be the standard bases for $\mathbb{R}^4$ and $\mathbb{R}^5$, respectively. Then $A = [u_1 \ \vec{0} \ u_3 \ u_4]$ and $B = [v_1 \ v_2 \ \vec{0}]$ satisfy the rank requirements, $AB\neq 0$, and $N(A)\subseteq R(B)$.

Answer (score 2):

This is a direct application of the [Sylvester's rank inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Properties): If $A \in M_{m \times n}$, $B \in M_{n \times k}$, then 
$$\text{rank}(AB) \geq \text{rank}(A) + \text{rank}(B) - n.$$

In your case, you have $\text{rank}(AB) \geq 3 + 2 - 4 = 1 > 0$, so the statement is true.